# Javascript - return keyword in Form vs Function

Tags: javascript

How does a return work in a Form vs a function?

I know you can `return false` in a function and it will stop the flow of the program,  great if you want to cancel a postback.  Why would I have a return in a Form as well?

Author snippet from beginning javascript book by Christian Heilmann:

```
<form action="whatever" method="post" onsubmit="return checkSearch();">

function checkSearch()
{
  alert ('foo');
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this this way:

```
function onsubmit(){
  return checkSearch();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When returning false from a function that handles an event, it will (generally) stop the default action.  So in the case of your example, if the `onSubmit` function returns false, the form will not submit (the default action).

Similarly, if you return false from an `onClick` event, the default action (following the link) is halted.  If you return true, the browser will attempt to follow the link after your script executes.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would I have a return in a Form as well?

Because *that* (returning false from the event handler) is what stops the flow of the program (in this case, further processing of the event). The `return false` from the function itself has no effect without that!

Comment: So when I return false from checkSearch without a return in Form, does the false just die/get ignored...?